# Vote locked, new insight (different commenter) makes me rethink the vote

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, locked-votes

I got this:

> You last voted on this answer Feb 8 '11 at 16:40 Your vote is now
>   locked in unless this answer is edited (click on this box to dismiss)

So this was shown to me on stackoverflow. I tried to remove an upvote to an already downvoted answer, I did not see that that the answer was really flawed. Another commenter saw this and responded. I wanted to take of my +1 (the tally was -1) so it would be a -2 which would mean more to visitors in my opinion.

I guess what I'm trying to say here is that a comment from somebody else other than the author (who clearly didn't take the downvotes as a hint) might influence my opinion.

This question is slightly different because the assumption is that your comment is picked up by the editor of the question.
[Should votes be unlocked after comments, not just edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112761/should-votes-be-unlocked-after-comments-not-just-edits)

Comment: So... are you asking to include the unlocking for votes also after comments or not? I don't see a feature-request tag so maybe it's not the case...

Comment: upvote the comment...

Comment: There should be no vote locking at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you change your mind about your vote on a post because it was clarified in a comment, edit the post to take the clarification into account, and then change your vote.

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't have 2k rep.

Comment: True enough....